# Multinomial response with repeated measures

Tags: r, categorical-data, repeated-measures, multinomial-distribution, ecology

I'm studying how sex influences habitat use. I'm looking for suggestions on how to analyze a repeated measure design with a multinomial response variable. I should note that the number of repeated measures varies with individual. I have 64 individuals with 240 trips. Basic model: `habitat` (3 categories) `~ sex` with `BirdID` as a repeated measure. I was going to use `glmer(habitat~sex+(1|BirdID))` but it does not have multinomial as a family option.

Data looks like the following:

```
Habitat BirdID  TripID  Sex
CP  3   24  Female
SO  3   25  Female
CP  3   26  Female
CP  57  88  Female
CP  57  89  Female
NSF 57  90  Female
SO  63  105 Female
CP  68  121 Male
CP  68  122 Male
CP  68  123 Male
```

I've tried and failed to get `mlogit` to work.

Comment: Is it too problematic for you to model it as two separate binomial models instead?

Comment: I don't think that will really answer my question as both sexes use all three habitats.